# Stealing user cookies with flash/actionscript

Tags: xss, flash

I know I am asking a dumb question here, but pardon me, I am learning.

I found two questions viz, [How do I access cookies within Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109580/how-do-i-access-cookies-within-flash) and 
[How to Make a button send an email using AS3 automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364958/how-to-make-a-button-send-an-email-using-as3-automatically). My question is, If I create a flash file with the above functionalities and upload that flash to some web applications like facebook or twitter, ideally I would be able to grab the cookies of other users in mailbox. What security feature is implemented in such cases to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your first link, flash is using javascript to read the cookie. Assuming that's the way you implement it, you are back to the usual cookie security restrictions:

- Same domain restrictions - the browser will only send cookies in the same domain, so *.foo.com cookies will only ever be sent to *.foo.com URLs. You would not be able to read a *.facebook.com cookie from foo.com
- HttpOnly flag - the cookie will only be sent over http/https connection and is not available to javascript. This would prevent your flash app reading any cookie with this flag.